# Does Sublime Text have a feature such as the Shift+Tab in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: sublimetext3, jupyter-notebook

I could not find a similar question. I have started using Sublime Text but it is frustrating after switching from Jupyter Notebook because when I hit shift+tab, it would show me all the parameters and the documentation of the method. But in sublime text I am not sure if I would be able to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand what you’re looking for you could try installing:

[codeintel](https://www.sublimecodeintel.com)